# How to assert a default exported function is called when mocking a module in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an external dependency in my Jest test.
My goal is to validate that the dependency was called with some specified arguments.

The dependency exports a default function, which makes it hard (impossible?) to use `jest.SpyOn`.

I've tried using `jest.mock` as follows:

```js
const callback = jest.fn(() => 'output');
jest.mock('dependecy', () => callback);

it('call dep with some args' () => {
    ...
    expect(callback).toBeCalledWith('arg1' , 'arg2')
});
```

Also tried `jest.mock('dependecy', () => ({ default: callback }));`.
But neither where successful, I was thinking this was because of the hoisting of `jest.mock`. Thus I've tried `jest.doMock`, but this does not even seem to call/create my mock.

Any ideas on how to validate that a method was called on an external dependency that exports a default function in jest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple working example that should get you going:

code.js

```js
import dependency from 'dependency';

export const func = () => 'returned ' + dependency();
```

code.test.js

```js
import { func } from './code';
import dependency from 'dependency';  // <= dependency will be...

jest.mock('dependency', () =>
  jest.fn(() => 'mocked')  // <= ...this mock function
);

describe('func', () => {
  it('should call dependency', () => {
    const result = func();
    expect(result).toBe('returned mocked');  // Success!
    expect(dependency).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```

Note that the module factory function must be self-contained so it can be hoisted by `babel-jest`.

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution! I wasn't aware that calling `expect` on the imported module would still reference the mocked instance.